# Getting ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed trying to connect to ElasticSearch deployed on kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, kubernetes

When I try to connect to ElasticSearch on kubernetes from my springBoot application outside kubernetes I get the following exception

```
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:922) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.17.6.jar:7.17.6]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:300) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.17.6.jar:7.17.6]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:288) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.17.6.jar:7.17.6]
        at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:146) ~[elasticsearch-java-7.17.6.jar:na]
        at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.index(ElasticsearchClient.java:939) ~[elasticsearch-java-7.17.6.jar:na]
        at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.index(ElasticsearchClient.java:956) ~[elasticsearch-java-7.17.6.jar:na]
```

ElasticSearch is up and running

```
kubectl get Elasticsearch quickstart
NAME         HEALTH   NODES   VERSION   PHASE   AGE
quickstart   green    1       7.16.2    Ready   2m2s
```

I can connect from my browser, using https not http

```
https://localhost:9200/
```

It does prompt for username and password I get

```
{
  "name" : "quickstart-es-default-0",
  "cluster_name" : "quickstart",
  "cluster_uuid" : "OtwzIl9LScalH4C6bK-Avg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.16.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "2b937c44140b6559905130a8650c64dbd0879cfb",
    "build_date" : "2021-12-18T19:42:46.604893745Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.10.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

My SpringBoot config is

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchConfiguration {

    /**
     * configure the host and port on which the elastic search is running on
     * @return
     */
    
    @Bean
    public RestClient getRestClient() {
         final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("elastic", "Y45f41ogIaxG592zr22u4XPv"));

            HttpHost host = new HttpHost("localhost", 9200);

            RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(host)
                    .setHttpClientConfigCallback(new HttpClientConfigCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            httpClientBuilder.disableAuthCaching();
                            return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
                        }
                    }).build();
            return restClient;
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchTransport getElasticsearchTransport() {
        return new RestClientTransport(getRestClient(), new JacksonJsonpMapper());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchClient getElasticsearchClient() {
        ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient(getElasticsearchTransport());
        return client;
    }
}
```

I am running on minikube ran the following commands

```
kubectl create -f https://download.elastic.co/downloads/eck/2.4.0/crds.yaml

kubectl apply -f https://download.elastic.co/downloads/eck/2.4.0/operator.yaml
```

Then ran the following deploy yaml for ElasticSearch

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: quickstart
spec:
  version: 7.16.2
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 1
    config:
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: elasticsearch
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 1Gi
              cpu: 900m
```

To allow access from outside

```
kubectl port-forward svc/quickstart-es-http 9200:9200
```

Is there another step I am missing. Going through stacktrace, they talk about security certificates. but none of the Tutorials mention any other authentication, apart from username, and password/secret.

i am using
elasticsearch-rest-client-7.17.6
With elasticsearch image 7.16.2

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?